# Looping on empty directory content in Bash

Tags: bash, loops

I'm writing a shell script in which I need to loop over directories and then loop over files inside them. So I've written this function:

```
loopdirfiles() {
    #loop over dirs
    for dir in "${PATH}"/*
    do
        for file in "${dir}"/*
            do
                echo $file
            done
    done
}
```

The problem is that it echoes something like *path/to/dir/** on empty directories.

Is there a way to use this approach and ignore those kind of directories?

Comment: If you are using `PATH` as a variable in your script **don't**. You will break running external commands as `PATH` is used for that. In general ALL_CAPS variables should be avoided (other than for script globals) as they are "reserved" for the shell's/etc. use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut the `*` from the directory name instead of completely ignoring it:

```
[[ $file == *"*" ]] && file="${file/%\*/}"
#this goes inside the second loop
```

Or if you want to ignore the empty directory:

```
[[ -d $dir && $ls -A $dir) ]] || continue
#this goes inside the first loop
```

Another way:

```
files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; echo "$dir"/*)
(( ${#files} )) || continue
#this goes inside the first loop
```

Or you can turn on the `nullglob` (mentioned by [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043243/3744681)) and `dotglob` altogether:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
#This goes before first loop.
```

---

[From Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shopt)

> nullglob
>
> If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to expand
>   to a null string, rather than themselves.
>
> dotglob
>
> If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a ‘.’ in the results of
>   filename expansion.

Note: `dotglob` includes hidden files (files with a `.` at the beginning in their names)

Comment: Running `ls` on a failed glob to determine if the glob failed is a relatively expensive test for this purpose.

Comment: @EtanReisner, It's on the first loop, where glob isn't failed..

Comment: Ah true. That's still a relatively expensive way to test for this situation since the failed glob is easily detectable (if you don't just avoid the problem with `nullglob`).

Comment: First one worked for me :)

Comment: @fedorqui yap, his was 15 minutes early... forgot that...edited...

Answer (score 12):

You can turn on the [`nullglob` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shopt). It causes unmatching globs to expand to an empty list instead of being left unexpanded.

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: I've set this option outside of the function and gave me the same result.

Comment: Make sure you are using `bash` and not `sh` and make sure you set that in the same shell session that you expect to use it (e.g. setting it in your current shell and then running a script with that function won't see it).